# Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, game-physics, game-development

`i'm a beginner programmer and need some help. I'm using android studio and libgdx. I created a project. When I try to use box2d", I get this error:`

> "Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

`Whenever I run a LibGDX project that uses box2d I always get a "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError" at the line where I initialize the world. I am just learning it in a tutorial series. I am trying to make am image into a physics body so it can fall. I think the problem may have something to do with the version of libGDX and android studio that I am using. Maybe both of them don't go too well. Please I would appreciate your help. Thank you.`

```
        public class MainGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
  
    @Override
    public void create() {
        texture = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
       world = new World(new Vector2(0, -98f),true);
        body = createBody();
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(sprite.getWidth()/2,sprite.getY()/2);
        FixtureDef fixtureDef  = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.density = 1f;
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        shape.dispose();
    }
}
```

> the error from my logcat when I ran the program is as shown below

```
        Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:135)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ikedinachim.com.MainGame.create(MainGame.java:31)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:151)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:128)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx-box2d64.dll' for target: Windows 10, 64-bit
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:125)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.<clinit>(World.java:187)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Unable to read file for extraction: gdx-box2d64.dll
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.readFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:133)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.loadFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:289)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:121)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add gdx-box2d-natives.jar to the libs directory of your desktop project if you are setting everything up on your own.

What I would recommend instead is that you use the libGDX setup application to create a skeleton project with all the dependencies setup, IDE integration created and then you can program within that without having to worry about fiddling about with libraries.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html